# How to extract rows from multiple pandas dataframes into one variable?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

As is now, I have rows from one dataframe (dataset) extracted into my variable (train). I would also like some rows from the dataset2. How would I do something similar to append certain rows from dataset2 onto train?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv')
dataset2 = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv')
train = dataset.loc[0:1450,:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html?highlight=append#pandas.DataFrame.append)

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv')
dataset2 = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv')
train = dataset.loc[0:1450,:]

train = train.append(dataset2.loc[0:1000,:],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I have tried this 
dataset2 = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv') #Len: 1599
dataset = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv') #Len: 4898

train = dataset.loc[0:4700,:]
test = dataset.loc[4700:4897,:]

train.append(dataset2.loc[0:1400,:],ignore_index=True)
test.append(dataset2.loc[1400:1597,:],ignore_index=True)

print(len(train))

Giving me a print of 4701, so it seems not to be doing the train.append

Comment: EDIT: Worked when I did train = train.append(), thank you!